# How to concatenate multi-indexed column dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, multi-index

I would like to make a somewhat complex multi-indexed column pandas dataframe concatenation. This concat consists of two or more dataframes in the following format:

```
indicator     eps2p                         ... logreturn                      
stock         TIET11     ALSC3     ALPA4    ...   TIET11  ALSC3 ALPA4    

date
2000-01-31       NaN       NaN       NaN    ...     NaN   NaN   NaN  
2000-02-01       100       NaN       NaN    ...     NaN   NaN   NaN  
2000-02-02       101       NaN       NaN    ...     NaN   NaN   NaN  
2000-02-03       104       NaN       NaN    ...     NaN   NaN   NaN 
2000-02-04       NaN       NaN       NaN    ...     NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Now, imagine that I have two more dataframes just like the one above, but instead of `eps2p` and `logreturn`, I have `ev2ebitda` and `logreturn`, and `ev2ebit` and `logreturn` in the `indicator` column level. Also, imagine that not all of the dataframes have the exact same `stock` columns under each one of the indicators. Finally, also consider that not necessarily two dataframes with the same `stock` under the same `indicator` have the exact same index, i.e., I could have two dataframes with the column `logreturn/TIET11`, but with complementary data:

```
DATAFRAME #1                   
              logreturn     
              TIET11        
date                        
2000-01-31    100       
2000-02-01    NaN       
2000-02-02    102
```

```
DATAFRAME #2                   
              logreturn     
              TIET11        
date                        
2000-01-31    100       
2000-02-01    101       
2000-02-02    NaN
```

With that in mind, how do I concat these dataframes into a single one that has all the unique indicator columns (`eps2p`, `ev2ebit` and `ev2ebitda`) and the common one (`logreturn`) in way that I don't have repeated data or lost data from any of the concatenated dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) to do this:

```
In [11]: df1.update(df2)

In [12]: df1
Out[12]:
           logreturn
              TIET11
date
2000-01-31     100.0
2000-02-01     101.0
2000-02-02     102.0
```

Since there are missing columns in df1 you can first reindex with the union:

```
res = df1.reindex(columns=df3.columns | df4.columns)
res.update(df2)
```

*Note: You may need to reindex the index too.*

Comment: Thanks Andy! Do you know if there is a way of doing this with more than only two dfs? Something similar to the pandas.concat function.

Comment: @nicolasfonteyne not by computer, but you can for loop through (update for each in the list), I don't think there's a direct method.